# Distribution of the mean of samples taken from two different distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Consider you have some distributions $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ of which you select $n_1$ samples from $Z_1$ and $n_2$ samples from $Z_2$.

We now add up these samples and take the mean. The question becomes, what is the distribution of $\mu$? Can this distribution be approximated via the CLT for sufficiently large values if $n$?

Normally this would be a standard CLT question if it involved just one distribution, but I am not sure how two different distributions with different sample sizes can effect this.

---

In case you want more specific examples of the problem, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are both uniform distributions on integers, just different ranges of integers. For example, $Z_1$ can be uniform selection of $\{1,2,3\}$ and $Z_2$ uniform selection of $\{4,5,6\}$

Comment: you can consider the total sample mean to be the sum of the two independent sub-means, and compute your desired statistics from there.